# mysql group_concat on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

This is the first time I ever use stackoverflow,.. be gentle on me ;)

I have little problem here with getting duplicated results from GROUP_CONCAT when using more than one JOIN on the map tables.

It is not easy to explain this, but I will try:

I have created a SQLFiddle for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2b347/3

I want the query to be just one instead of 1 for all of the posts and then hammering on every test. But since the GROUP_CONCAT is merging those test results I am getting twice as much data than I want.

It is possible somehow to make the query more reliable. To always have the GROUP_CONCAT to be the exact numbers of tests?

I expect/want the output to be:

```
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
| post_id | flows           | flow_types | powers  | power_types |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       1 | 100,140         | a,b        | 1,1     | a,b         |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       2 | 200,200,200     | a,b,c      | (null)  | (null)      |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
```

but it is:

```
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
| post_id | flows           | flow_types | powers  | power_types |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       1 | 100,100,140,140 | a,a,b,b    | 1,1,1,1 | a,b,a,b     |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       2 | 200,200,200     | a,b,c      | (null)  | (null)      |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
```

and with GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT I get:

```
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
| post_id | flows           | flow_types | powers  | power_types |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       1 | 100,140         | a,b        | 1       | a,b         |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
|       2 | 200             | a,b,c      | (null)  | (null)      |
|---------|-----------------|------------|---------|-------------|
```

Here is the create query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_post` (`post`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts_test1`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts_test1` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test1_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`test1_id`,`type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` (
  `test1_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flow` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test1_id`),
  KEY `IDX_FLOW` (`flow`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts_test2`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts_test2` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test2_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`test2_id`,`type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test2`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
  `test2_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `power` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test2_id`),
  KEY `IDX_POWER` (`power`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `types`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `types` (
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `types` (`type_id`, `type`) VALUES
  (1, 'a'),
  (2, 'b'),
  (3, 'c');

INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `post`) VALUES
  (1, 'test1'),
  (2, 'test2');

INSERT INTO `test1` (`test1_id`, `flow`) VALUES
  (1, 100),
  (2, 140),
  (3, 200),
  (4, 200),
  (5, 200);

INSERT INTO `posts_test1` (`post_id`, `test1_id`, `type_id`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (1, 2, 2),
  (2, 3, 1),
  (2, 4, 2),
  (2, 5, 3);

INSERT INTO `test2` (`test2_id`, `power`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1);

INSERT INTO `posts_test2` (`post_id`, `test2_id`, `type_id`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (1, 2, 2);
```

And here are my select queries..

```
SELECT
p.post_id, p.post,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.flow) flow,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1t.type) flow_types
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_test1 pt1 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test1 t1 USING (test1_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t1t ON (t1t.type_id = pt1.type_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id; # works fine


SELECT
p.post_id, p.post,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.power) powers,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2t.type) power_types
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_test2 pt2 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test2 t2 USING (test2_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t2t ON (t2t.type_id = pt2.type_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id; # works fine


SELECT
p.post_id, p.post,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.flow) flow,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1t.type) flow_types,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.power) powers,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2t.type) power_types
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_test1 pt1 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test1 t1 USING (test1_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t1t ON (t1t.type_id = pt1.type_id)
LEFT JOIN posts_test2 pt2 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test2 t2 USING (test2_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t2t ON (t2t.type_id = pt2.type_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id; # getting duplicated GROUP_CONCAT results

SELECT
p.post_id, p.post,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.flow) flow,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1t.type) flow_types,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.power) powers,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2t.type) power_types
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_test1 pt1 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test1 t1 USING (test1_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t1t ON (t1t.type_id = pt1.type_id)
LEFT JOIN posts_test2 pt2 USING (post_id)
    LEFT JOIN test2 t2 USING (test2_id)
        LEFT JOIN types t2t ON (t2t.type_id = pt2.type_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id; # DISTINCT wipes the GROUP_CONCAT if same result...
```

Thanks and have a nice day!!

edit: added expected result as suggest, thanks :)

Comment: Please add expected output in tabular formatting to the question. By the way, well done on the question formulation :)

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya added the expected results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that there are two different junction tables (and two different connection chains), originating from a single table `post`. So a linear `JOIN` chain does not work. Duplicates in one of the junction table leads to duplication in other chain, when linear joining is done.

One way is to consider these two different `JOIN` chains in two separate [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subqueries inside the `FROM` clause), and determine their respective grouped/aggregated expressions. We can then `JOIN` back these two chains using `post_id`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  dt1.post_id, 
  dt1.flows, 
  dt1.flow_types, 
  dt2.powers, 
  dt2.power_types 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    p.post_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.flow) AS flows, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(typ.type) AS flow_types
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN posts_test1 pt1 
    ON pt1.post_id = p.post_id 
  LEFT JOIN test1 t1 
    ON t1.test1_id = pt1.test1_id 
  LEFT JOIN types typ 
    ON typ.type_id = pt1.type_id 
  GROUP BY p.post_id 
) AS dt1 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    p.post_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.power) AS powers, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(typ.type) AS power_types 
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN posts_test2 pt2 
    ON pt2.post_id = p.post_id 
  LEFT JOIN test2 t2 
    ON t2.test2_id = pt2.test2_id 
  LEFT JOIN types typ 
    ON typ.type_id = pt2.type_id 
  GROUP BY p.post_id 
) AS dt2
  ON dt1.post_id = dt2.post_id;
```

**Result**

```
| post_id | flows       | flow_types | powers | power_types |
| ------- | ----------- | ---------- | ------ | ----------- |
| 1       | 100,140     | a,b        | 1,1    | a,b         |
| 2       | 200,200,200 | a,b,c      |        |             |
```

---

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ctDHDviuGj4gux1fJznVAg/0)

Comment: Thanks Madhur :)

I was hoping to avoid using subquery since I need to do way more than just 2 "mapped joins"

Comment: @TLBang I don't believe that it is solvable without using subqueries; due to different join chains. Other possible solution would involve correlated subqueries.

Comment: @TLBang writing a large query should not be an issue as long it is performant (with proper indexing defined) and does the job.